# DNS records at Azure and Google - do both need the entire set of records?

Tags: domain-name-system

We are migrating from Azure to Google.  Google is currently storing our DNS records.  Simply put, do we need to put all the A records in both places?  Or is DNS smart enough to loop through it's list of name servers until it finds a name server with the record?

Say for example:

Google has A record 1.1.1.1 to foo.com

Azure has A record 2.2.2.2 to bar.foo.com

Do I need to add the A record for bar.foo.com to google as well?

Comment: **We are migrating from Azure to Google** - What does that mean, exactly? **Google is currently storing our DNS records** - If Google is currently hosting your DNS then wouldn't you already have all of your A records at Google? Why would you have A records at Azure?

Comment: `is DNS smart enough to loop through it's list of name servers until it finds a name server with the record?` No. DNS will not do that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the same set of resource records on all your name servers. A DNS resolver requests one DNS server randomly from all designated by the NS records. If the selected DNS server responds then no further requests to other DNS servers. If the DNS server says `bar.foo.com is unknown` then the DNS resolver accepts this answer and caches it, no further requests are made.